# offset().top not returning correct value on appending element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a box containing several inputs and a link, when I click on the link an input is appended to the box. Now each time the link is clicked I want the box to be scrolled to the last input in the box.
With the solution below it works fine at first but then it returns incorrect `offset().top` value.
How can I fix this?

in html I have:

```
<div class="team-emails-outer">
  <div class="team-emails-inner overflow-auto">
    <div class="form-group forms">
      <input type="email" class="form-control form-input" aria-describedby="email" autocomplete="off">
        <span class="input-line" data-placeholder="Ex. name@example.com"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group forms">
      <input type="email" class="form-control form-input" aria-describedby="email" autocomplete="off">
       <span class="input-line" data-placeholder="Ex. name@example.com"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group forms">
      <input type="email" class="form-control form-input" aria-describedby="email" autocomplete="off">
        <span class="input-line" data-placeholder="Ex. name@example.com"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="add-teammate-link d-flex flex-row-reverse text-right">
   <a href="#" id="addAnother">{% trans "add another" %}</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

in js I have:

```
$('#addAnother').click(function() {
    let height_diff = Math.round($('.container-fluid').innerHeight() - $('nav').innerHeight() - $('#spaceTeammatesBox').innerHeight()),
        emails_length = $('#spaceTeammatesBox .team-emails-inner').find('.forms').length,
        form_height = (Number(emails_length) * Number($('#spaceTeammatesBox .team-emails-inner').find('.forms').innerHeight())) + Number($('#spaceTeammatesBox .team-emails-inner').find('.forms').innerHeight());

        height_diff > 180 ? $('.team-emails-inner').css('height', form_height + 'px') : null;

    $('#spaceTeammatesBox').find('.form-group.forms').last().after(`
        <div class="form-group forms">
            <input type="email" class="form-control form-input" aria-describedby="email" autocomplete="off">
            <span class="input-line" data-placeholder="Ex. name@example.com"></span>
        </div>
    `);
   // this section ***
   $('.team-emails-inner').animate({
      scrollTop: $(".forms").last().offset().top + Number($('#spaceTeammatesBox .team-emails-inner').find('.forms').innerHeight())
   }, 1000);
});
```